# Использование не классического конструктора копирования

Tags: c++

```
Object(Object & obj)
```

Есть ли причины для использования данного конструктора?

На ум приходит только `auto_ptr`, хотя это скорее плохой пример.

Comment: Ну мало ли - вдруг требуется выставлять в объекте флаг, был ли этот объект скопирован...

Comment: При использовании прототипного подхода может понадобится передать ссылку на изменяемый объект для получения ссылки на изменяемый прототип для инициализации прототипа данного объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Есть случаи, когда объект должен хранить память эксклюзивно. Без внешнего вмешательства. В этом случае конструктор у аргумента изымает данную память, оставляет себе.

```
//  g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c++98 secr.cpp
class Secret {
  int * pointer ;
public:
  Secret (Secret & o) : pointer ( o.pointer ) { o.pointer = 0 ; }
  Secret (Secret const & )  ; // без определения
  explicit  Secret(int * * x) : pointer(*x) { (*x) = 0 ; }
  ~Secret(){delete pointer;}
} ;

void f(){
  int * pi = new int(1);
  Secret s(&pi) ;
  delete pi ; // здесь pi указывает на NULL - ничего не удалится
  Secret s2(s);
  // здесь s с указателем NULL - пустой
  // а s2 хранит указатель и сам удаляет память
  }
```

Comment: Но это именно то, для чего предназначен конструктор *перемещения*! Суть вопроса-то именно в том и состоит: зачем в современном С++, поддерживающем концепцию перемещения, может понадобится конструктор копирования с неконстантным аргументом.

Comment: @AnT, например, можно предположить ситуацию, когда все копии объекта должны быть в связанном списке. То есть придумать некое применение возможно, но вот насколько оно будет соотноситься с реальными задачами это большой вопрос. Можно сказать, что с появлением конструктора перемещения неконстантное копирование себя изжило.